# How do i stream a mp3 file instead of microphone data in opentok session

Tags: opentok

We need to stream audio file user selects instead of default microphone. Is there any option in SDK to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a native SDK such as iOS, Android or Windows you should build your own audio driver.

See our samples:

- iOS: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift/tree/master/Custom-Audio-Driver
- Android: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Custom-Audio-Driver

That audio driver will open the mp3 file and will send it over the OpenTok session.

Comment: There isn't a provision to source a mp3 file into these drivers. Any help?

Comment: The opentok audio driver is expecting uncompressed PCM audio, if you want to send a mp3 file you need to uncompress the mp3 audio and feed the driver with that output

Comment: Nope, mp3 decoding is very fast, take a look to any of the libraries you can find under "mp3 decoding ios/android"

Comment: Any help can you offer to implement this as we are not able to pass any stream

Comment: We are not sure what mofiications are needed and where. We need to browse a audio file and then stream that as a audio source for tokbox session. We converted mp3 to bytebuffer and tried passing it but did not succeed. We are struck here for sometime now. Let me know you can offer any help

Comment: You cannot just read MP3 file raw data and send it to the audio driver since that raw data is MP3 encoded audio. OpenTok audio driver is expecting raw uncompressed (PCM) audio. You can use AudioToolbox library to read the contents of the file, decompress it and then, send that data to the OpenTok audio driver. Take a look to AudioToolbox classes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/extended_audio_file_services . You should be able to read the file contents by calling `ExtAudioFileRead`

Comment: @HyLian Does this class work https://gist.github.com/shakil807g/105c84eb055057f5af99ed5b6e0986b9 ? but i still don't understand how to use it with opentok can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the opentok.js SDK then you can use the Fetch API to fetch the mp3 file and the web audio API to decode the audio data and create a media stream destination out of it. Then you can take the audio track from that stream and pass it to the audioSource in OT.initPublisher.

Here is a sample that loads an mp3 file into a session.

https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Stereo-Audio